# Algebra of limits- Is this proof correct?

Tags: analysis, limits

If you go to http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Algebra_of_Limits

Shouldn't the line before the last line read $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {1}{y_{n}} = \frac {1}{y}$$

Instead of

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {1}{y_{n}} = y$$

No need to explain but please tell me if it's wrong or not. (Or if there's a better proof available online)

Comment: You probably meant $y_n$ in which case you are right: it should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{y_n}=\frac{1}{y}$.

Comment: @KimJongUn Oh no! Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks. I'll fix that for future readers.